# Very long string is getting overflown in the pdf

Tags: formatting, line-breaking

I am very new to latex/ .tex files. Need some help here please.

I am creating a PDF file with some information and in the end of the file there is a placeholder called `signature`. Signature is a very long string with no spaces inbetween. For example:
`qwertyuiiuytrdsdfghjkiuyfdcvbnjkiuytfdcvbnmkjhgfdcvbnjhgfdcvbnjhgfcvbnjhgvcqwertyuiiuytrdsdfghjkiuyfdcvbnjkiuytfdcvbnmkjhgfdcvbnjhgfdcvbnjhgfcvbnjhgvcqwertyuiiuytrdsdfghjkiuyfdcvbnjkiuytfdcvbnmkjhgfdcvbnjhgfdcvbnjhgfcvbnjhgvcqwertyuiiuytrdsdfghjkiuyfdcvbnjkiuytfdcvbnmkjhgfdcvbnjhgfdcvbnjhgfcvbnjhgvcqwertyuiiuytrdsdfghjkiuyfdcvbnjkiuytfdcvbnmkjhgfdcvbnjhgfdcvbnjhgfcvbnjhgvcqwertyuiiuytrdsdfghjkiuyfdcvbnjkiuytfdcvbnmkjhgfdcvbnjhgfdcvbnjhgfcvbnjhgvcqwertyuiiuytrdsdfghjkiuyfdcvbnjkiuytfdcvbnmkjhgfdcvbnjhgfdcvbnjhgfcvbnjhgvcqwertyuiiuytrdsdfghjkiuyfdcvbnjkiuytfdcvbnmkjhgfdcvbnjhgfdcvbnjhgfcvbnjhgvcqwertyuiiuytrdsdfghjkiuyfdcvbnjkiuytfdcvbnmkjhgfdcvbnjhgfdcvbnjhgfcvbnjhgvc`

This string is getting overflown in the pdf. I tried using `tabularx`, `mbox`, `hbox` and other tags to solve the issue, but it still doesnt work.

Below is my .tex file

```
\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}>{\columncolor{white}}p{0.5\textwidth}  @{}>{\columncolor{white}}p{0.5\textwidth}}
\textbf{Name}& \placeholder{.name} \\
\textbf{Client reference}& \placeholder{.clientReference} 
\end{tabularx}

\vspace*{2em}

By signing this document I confirm the following declarations vis-à-vis Scalable Capital:
\begin{itemize}
    \item[$\bullet$] I act in my own name and for my own account.
\end{itemize}

\medskip

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}>{\columncolor{white}}p{1\textwidth}} \bfseries
    This document has been generated on the basis of the data entered by you on \placeholder{.date} at \placeholder{.time} .
\end{tabularx}

\medskip

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}>{\columncolor{white}}p{1\textwidth}}
The is another text
\end{tabularx}

\vspace*{2em}

\rule{\textwidth}{0.5pt}\\

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}>{\columncolor{white}}p{1\textwidth}}
\placeholder{.signature}\\
\end{tabularx}


\rule{\textwidth}{0.5pt}\\
\placeholder{.signature}\\
\rule{\textwidth}{0.5pt}

\end{document}
```

Any suggestions please?

Comment: check the seqsplit package.

Comment: Thank you @UlrikeFischer it works :)